# In Vue, how do you want to add styles to this tabbox component and remove the styles that are added to other tabbox components?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, components

In Vue, what should I do when I want to click a component to add styles to this component and to clean up the additional styles that have been clicked on other tabbox components before? Thanks in advance!

Here is the code of the sub component

```
<template>
   <div :class="tabStyle" :style="boxstyle"     @click="tabClick(name)">
     {{name}}
     <div class="selected-icon" v-show="isSelected"></div> <!--selected styles-->
     <div class="tick" v-show="isSelected"></div>   <!--selected styles-->
   </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  name: "tabbox",
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    },
    boxstyle: {
     type: Object,
     defalult: {}
   }
 },
data() {
    return {
      isSelected: false,
      tabStyle: {
        "selected-box": false,
        "unselected-box": true
      }
    };
},
methods: {
    tabClick(name) {
      this.isSelected = true;         
      this.borderChange("selected-box","unselected-box")//style add
      this.$emit("getTabName", name);
    },
    borderChange(first, second) {
      this.tabStyle[first] = true;
      this.tabStyle[second] = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>


 <style lang="scss" scoped>
.tab-box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 20%;
}
.unselected-box {
  border: solid 1px #b9a7a76b;
  @extend .tab-box;
}
.selected-box {
  border: solid 1px #5ddb14;
  @extend .tab-box;
}
.selected-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: #5ddb14 transparent;
  border-width: 0 0 20px 25px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.tick {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  &::after {
    content: "✓";
  }
}
</style>
```

And This is the code of the parent component

```
<template>
    <div class="select-tab" :style="tabStyle">
        <Header></Header>


        <div class="label-content" v-for="(item,index) in categories" :key="index">
            <meaning-label :name="item.name"></meaning-label>
            <div class="box-content">
                <TabBox @getTabName="getTabName" :name="_item.name" :boxstyle="styles" v-for="(_item,_index) in item.categoryList" :key="_index">
                </TabBox>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import TabBox from "@/components/FindMusic/SelectTab/TabBox";
import MeaningLabel from "@/components/FindMusic/SelectTab/MeaningLabel";
import Header from "@/components/FindMusic/SelectTab/Header";
export default {
  components: {
    TabBox,
    MeaningLabel,
    Header
  },
  methods: {},
  data() {
    return {
      styles: {
        width: ""
      },
      allStyles: {
        width: "94%",
        margin: "2px 1.5%"
      },
      _categories: {}
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.categories = this.$store.state.CategoriesInfo.categories;
  },
  props: {
    tabStyle: {
      type: Object,
      default: {}
    },
    categories: {
      type:Array,
      default: []
    }
  },
  methods: {       
    getTabName(name){
      this.$emit('getTabName',name)
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.box-content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 75%;
  font-size: 0;
}
.label-content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Just keep the style on the tab i click right now and remove the style i has clicked before .

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is get boxstyle from a Vue method:

```
<template>
    <div class="select-tab" :style="tabStyle">
        <Header></Header>


        <div class="label-content" v-for="(item,index) in categories" :key="index">
            <meaning-label :name="item.name"></meaning-label>
            <div class="box-content">
                <TabBox @getTabName="getTabName" :name="_item.name" :boxstyle="getTableStyle(_item.name)" v-for="(_item,_index) in item.categoryList" :key="_index">
                </TabBox>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import TabBox from "@/components/FindMusic/SelectTab/TabBox";
import MeaningLabel from "@/components/FindMusic/SelectTab/MeaningLabel";
import Header from "@/components/FindMusic/SelectTab/Header";
export default {
  components: {
    TabBox,
    MeaningLabel,
    Header
  },
  methods: {},
  data() {
    return {
      styles: {
        width: ""
      },
      allStyles: {
        width: "94%",
        margin: "2px 1.5%"
      },
      _categories: {},
      activeTabName: ''
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.categories = this.$store.state.CategoriesInfo.categories; 
    // you might want to set default activeTabName here or in Vue's watch
  },
  props: {
    tabStyle: {
      type: Object,
      default: {}
    },
    categories: {
      type:Array,
      default: []
    }
  },
  methods: {       
    getTabName(name){
      this.$emit('getTabName',name)
      this.activeTabName = name
    },
    getTableStyle (name) {
      if (name === this.activeTabName) {
        return this.allStyles
      }
      return {}
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.box-content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 75%;
  font-size: 0;
}
.label-content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
```